# Regex expressions for some commands

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find the regex expressions to treat the following commands:

- look [filename=”file_a.dat” filesize>”1048576”],I did something like that:
  "^look \[filename="([[:graph:]]+)" filesize>"[0-9]+"]$" and it seems isn't working.
- announce listen 2222 seed [file_a.dat 2097152 1024 8905e92afeb80fc7722ec89eb0bf0966 file_b.dat 3145728 1536 330a57722ec8b0bf09669a2b35f88e9e leech [ssssa delhd433jh2 sdjhgd44432dskj3], I did something like that "^announce listen (([[:digit:]]+)) seed \[(([[:graph:]]+ [[:digit:]]+ [[:digit:]]+ [[:lower:][:digit:]]+)?( [[:graph:]]+ [[:digit:]]+ [[:digit:]]+ [[:lower:][:digit:]]+)*)\]$"

I'm using the regex_t api in C with posix extended expressions

Answer (score 0):

The first one fails because the string contains the wrong kind of double-quotes.

For the second one I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, in the general case. If you remove `\]$` from the end of the regex it matches up to just before  `leech`. I suppose `leech` would match against `[[:graph:]]+`, but the next part would fail because `[` doesn't match `[[:digit:]]`.

Comment: What kind of double-quote I should add ?

Comment: for the second one the leech is optional we could have a leech there or not I tried to use ? after the leech but it doesn't work I don"t know exactly how I'll do it

Comment: @LinuxLover The character you posted in the string isn't the usual ascii double-quote (ascii hex code `22`). It's the unicode character `201D`.

Even with the `?`, there's still nothing that can match the string `[ssssa delhd433jh2 sdjhgd44432dskj3]`. And you've got `$` at the end, so it won't do a partial match.

Comment: Hi for commands like this one: announce listen 2222 seed [file_a.dat 2097152 1024 8905e92afeb80fc7722ec89eb0bf0966 file_b.dat 3145728 1536 330a57722ec8b0bf09669a2b35f88e9e] leech [330a57722ec8b0bf09669a2b35f88e9e]